# Why is minimodding bad?

Tags: moderators

A [minimod is](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Minimod):

> "A normal forum poster that takes it upon themselves to push forum rules and tell everybody how to conduct themselves instead of leaving it up to the mods. Typically reserved for people that don't know what they're talking about, act like they have some kind of authority, and/or are obviously doing what they're doing to try to score points with the real mods and become moderators themselves. (especially if it becomes a regular thing for them and/or they don't contribute much good to the community otherwise)
> A typical minimod would go into a thread where several members are in an intense, hostile argument that hasn't degenerated to the point where nobody's having an intellectual discussion anymore and tell everybody to stop flaming and trolling each other, and possibly that they'll be banned if they continue."

I am trying to figure out why exactly this is bad. Shouldn't it be in the interst of every member of a community to uphold the written down rules of the community?

Comment: Related: https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/minimodding---what-it-is-and-why-it-isnt-allowed/

Answer (score 3):

While yes mini-modding can be helpful in some cases it can also cause harm.

#### How it can help

- It can stop new users from breaking smaller rules they didn't mean to and learn from it.
- It could possibly slow large arguments especially if that member is known in the community.

#### How it can cause harm

- That member may not be an expert and may not actively monitor the TOS and other related documents for changes and what they are saying could be outdated.
- People may mistake them as a real moderator and share sensitive info with them even though they may not be trustworthy.
- They can be flat-out wrong. Now this can also happen with mods. But moderators tend to be experts on the rules and have the most up-to-date and comprehensive knowledge of them while community members may not.
- If they get targeted by trolls with insults, doxxing etc the company (if applicable) may not need to provide help to them as they were not under contract or anything. Meaning it could possibly cause significant harm to them.